# Google Analytics javascript seems running, but Fiddler shows nothing communication with Google

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, google-analytics, fiddler

I am running my ASP.NET page from VS 2013 using IIS Express. I am monitoring the https traffic with fiddler. The Google analytics code is this:

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
i[r] = i[r] || function () {
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments);
}, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
a.async = 1;
a.src = g;
m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I can see all the requests to localhost, the page, the css, the images etc in Fiddler, even the request to www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js, however no other request are shown to google. I am using Chrome, after pressing F12 I set the breakpoint to ga('create'... ) and ga('send'....). The breakpoint is hit, and when I single step execute it happens nothing in Fiddler.

Should not I see the request to google with some analytical data, most importantly my UA- code?

Missed I something?

Thx in advance

Comment: Can you share the site?

Comment: Have you enabled HTTPS decryption in Fiddler?

Comment: @Eric Hi, I was hoped you will see the Fiddler tag, and are ready to help as always :-). (Btw with Fiddler you have been already helped me so much I can not express and thank enough.) So... There is no trace to initiate a https session. I think even in case I do not enable the https decryption the https session initiation should must shown in Fiddler.

Comment: @Blexy: Unfortunately I can not share the site, as it belongs to one of my client.

Comment: It's true that if you haven't enabled HTTPS decryption, you'd typically see a `CONNECT` tunnel, but that can be hidden by options on the `Rules` menu. Have you tried the `Help` > `Troubleshoot Filters` command?